# Redirect users to their profile after login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I want to redirect users to their profiles instead of the laravel's default /home page. I have tried this in my LoginController: `protected $redirectTo = '/profile/{id}';` but it returns this error:

> User with id:{id} not found.

This is my route: `Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@profile');`

This is my profile controller method:

```
public function profile(Request $request, $id){
  $User = User::with(['complains'])->find($id);
  if(!$User) return abort(404, 'User with id:'.$id.' not found');

  return view('user.profile')->with(['user' => $User, 'complains' => $User-
  >complains]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id protected `$redirectTo = '/profile/1';`
or

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
`$redirectTo = '/profile/$id';`
```

If you use Auth use it in the LoginController file as Use Auth;

Comment: This doesn't work.  I tried
`protected $id = Auth::user()->id;
    protected $redirectTo = '/author/$id';`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware to achieve this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->action('ProfileController@profile', Auth::user()->id);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me a very long time to get and just to help another. The redirectTo() method needs a string as response and not a further redirection since it is a redirection itself and from the laravel documentation, the function is of type string. so you can do this:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    /*
      You can add any other logic needed to be satisfied here or 
      flash some sessional data here,etc.       
    */
    return 'profile/'.auth()->user()->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I know that I am late but I think it's good place to leave what I made for others with the same problem, so I made a one route which is default after login `Route::get('/home', 'PagesController@index');` and then I made a function in PagesController:

```
public function index(){
    $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
    return view('pages/profile' ['user'=>$user,]); 
}
```

So when you login, it passes user data to the pages/profile.blade.php view and work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to pass id on redirect route.
You can get id of auth user in controller so I would like to suggest,

```
 Route::get('/profile/{id?}', 'ProfileController@profile');

public function profile(Request $request, $id = NULL){
   $id = !empty($id) ? $id : Auth::user()->id;
  $User = User::with(['complains'])->find($id);
  if(!$User) return abort(404, 'User with id:'.$id.' not found');

  return view('user.profile')->with(['user' => $User, 'complains' => $User-
  >complains]);
}
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Paste in your homeController

```
public function index()
{
    return Redirect::to('profile/' .auth()->user()->id);
}
```